# UITableCellView deselects when long pressing the table with no callback

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm having a problem handling the case where the currently selected cell in a table deselects when you long-press the table.

Repro:

1. Have a UITableView with several cells
2. Tap a cell to select it (should turn blue or follow its selection style)
3. Long press another cell

Result:
The currently selected cell deselects, but does not trigger the UITableViewDelegate methods `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` or `didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath`.

Expected Result:
There should be some kind of callback so that I can handle this case.

The selected table cell does receive a `setSelected:NO animated:NO` message when this happens, but that's hardly adequate to track the state of the table itself. Is there some other callback I'm unaware of? Am I missing something?

I have tried using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, but that seems to steal the event handling from the table view in an undesirable fashion.

This is currently happening with an iOS 6.0 device, our app supports down to version 4.3.

Comment: What version iOS you working with?

Comment: Edited the question with this info. Running 6.0, supporting 4.3+.

Answer (score 0):

if the new selected row does trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, you can try to implement a couple of flags to determine the currently selected row and the previously selected row so when didSelectRowAtIndexPath triggers you can valdidate that the currentlySelectedRow (now the old one) is different to what the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: reports on it's NSIndexPath parameter, if so you can handle an action on the previously selected row.

Hope this can give you some insight.

Comment: That's not the situation I'm dealing with. I'm trying to handle specifically when a cell deselects when you long-press the table. Once you let go and a new selection is made, everything is fine, but I'm not receiving the callback for when the original cell is first deselected on long-press.